# Why do we use RMS speed rather than just taking the average of absolute value of the speeds?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

I get that negative values to cancel positive values, and that is the reason why we don't do a direct average. So why don't we just use the absolute value mean of the speed?

If I have one gas particle moving at $5m/s$ and one moving at $-3m/s$, yes, the average of those gives $1m/s$, sure, so why don't we just make $3$ positive and then take the average? Isn't $4$ more representative of the actual mean than the RMS speed? (which would be 5.83)

Comment: where do you ad speeds of molecules? usually you consider their energy so you have v^2 an take the mein of this.

Comment: Take the mean of the speed to determine what?

Comment: Arithmetic note: the mean of the squares of $(5,-3)$ is $(25+9)/2=17$, so the r.m.s. is 4.1. Your result in v1 of the question is incorrect.

Comment: @rob you're right i forgot to divide by 2 before squaring, thanks

Comment: we use whatever is useful

Comment: I personally think this is an interesting question. I think the answer may be related to the definition of nth average using the maxwell Boltzmann distribution but I'm not really sure.

As an extra note, I don't understand @AndrewSteane's comment because why is the way to measure average that op proposes, not useful?

Comment: @Buraian sorry for the late reply but i think it's because kinetic energy is often considered so it's useful to have rms speed so you can square it and have sum of all squared speeds which would be used in calculating total kinetic energy

Answer (score 2):

I am not a math expert or a physics expert, but I *think* it comes down to this: $f(x)=x^2$ is a [*differentiable function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function), but $|x|$ is *not* differentiable. That means, there are more mathematically valid ways in which you can make use of the RMS average of a signal than if you simply computed the arithmetic mean of its absolute value.